# Flask flash breaks after redirect

Tags: python, flask

In my test case,

```
with self.client:
  r = self.client.get('/admin/')
  print get_flashed_messages()
```

I see the following output:

```
[u"You must be signed in to access 'http://Testing/admin/'."]
```

However, when I set `follow_redirects=True`,

```
with self.client:
  r = self.client.get('/admin/', follow_redirects=True)
  print r.data
```

with this template:

```
  <div class='container'>
    <div id="main-div" class="with-margins">
      FLASH MESSAGE HERE: {{ get_flashed_messages() }}
```

I see the following output:

```
 <div class='container'>
    <div id="main-div" class="with-margins">

      FLASH MESSAGE HERE: []
```

Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

CODE:

```
class AuthTestConfig(TestingConfig):
  TESTING = False
  LOGIN_DISABLED = False

class AccessControlTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.app = create_app(AuthTestConfig)
    self.client = self.app.test_client()

  def tearDown(self):
    pass

  def test_anon_visits_member_redirects_to_login(self):
    from flask import get_flashed_messages

    with self.client:
      r = self.client.get('/admin/', follow_redirects=True)
      #print get_flashed_messages()
      print r.data
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/) there is this excerpt:

> The flashing system basically makes it possible to record a message at
>   the end of a request and access it next request and only next request

So, when you render template, `get_flashed_messages`  removes flashed message from session and as a result, you can't access it in your test case.  So you should turn off rendering (render_templates = False in TestCase)

Comment: If that is the case, how is Flask-User able to test the flash messages? (Line 44 and 45) 

https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/v0.6/flask_user/tests/test_authorization.py